# Copy Button not showing in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am showing a dialog with existing name pre-filled in the `TextView`.

I want to show "Copy Text" option which is not being shown by default when text portion in selected. Please suggest. Right not it is only showing Text Selection without Copy button.

following is my existing code.

```
final TextViewinput = new TextView(this); 
            input.setTextIsSelectable(true);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Edit File Name")
            .setView(input).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Pre-HoneyComb use :-

```
import android.text.ClipboardManager;

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        cm.setText(textView.getText());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks.. but i dont need this.. i want to settextisselectable to work some how...